# building shared library (.so) for android

Tags: android, c, shared-libraries

I have a small C library source code and I want to use this code in android.

As far as i understand,  I have to make this C code into a shared library `.so` using `NDK`,

**Question :**
How to build a shared library (.so) using Android Studio

Comment: hope that after almost 9 years you can provide an answer? :)